# Accidentally renamed a Composer file

Tags: composer

I found some answers suggesting ways to discover original file name but those seem to be irrelevant here, I wonder if anyone recognizes the content below and can suggest the original file name.

Original location is the parent folder of 'vendor'.

Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
/*
 * This file is part of Composer.
 *
 * (c) Nils Adermann <naderman@naderman.de>
 *     Jordi Boggiano <j.boggiano@seld.be>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view
 * the license that is located at the bottom of this file.
 */

// Avoid APC causing random fatal errors per https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/264
if (extension_loaded('apc') && filter_var(ini_get('apc.enable_cli'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) && filter_var(ini_get('apc.cache_by_default'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)) {
    if (version_compare(phpversion('apc'), '3.0.12', '>=')) {
        ini_set('apc.cache_by_default', 0);
    } else {
        fwrite(STDERR, 'Warning: APC <= 3.0.12 may cause fatal errors when running composer commands.'.PHP_EOL);
        fwrite(STDERR, 'Update APC, or set apc.enable_cli or apc.cache_by_default to 0 in your php.ini.'.PHP_EOL);
    }
}

if (!class_exists('Phar')) {
    echo 'PHP\'s phar extension is missing. Composer requires it to run. Enable the extension or recompile php without --disable-phar then try again.' . PHP_EOL;
    exit(1);
}

Phar::mapPhar('composer.phar');
require 'phar://composer.phar/bin/composer';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is more relevant in stackoverflow than askubuntu but I'll give it a shot

Searched https://github.com/composer/composer for the content of this file and found https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/main/src/Composer/Compiler.php

Based on that file I suspect the original filename was `composer.phar`

But to be sure, it's best you take your `composer.json`, install a fresh `composer` and run `install` - you should be able to find your file there

Side-note: an answer that might be fitting askubuntu is that you should try using git or another VCS to keep track of your files.

Comment: Nice tidy answer, well done for identifying that it is likely better shared in another community. That and linking possible duplicates needs to be done more often.